# Auto delete PVC when scaling down?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

I am looking for a way to delete PersistentVolumeClaims assigned to pods of a StatefulSet automatically when I scale down the number of instances. Is there a way to do this within k8s? I haven't found anything in the docs, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that a [`preStop` Lifecycle Handler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#lifecycle-v1-core) could submit a `Job` to clean up the PVC, assuming the Pod's `ServiceAccount` had the `Role` to do so. Unfortunately, the Lifecycle Handler docs say that the `exec` blocks the Pod deletion, so that's why whatever happened would need to be asynchronous from the Pod's perspective.

Another approach might be to unconditionally scan the cluster or namespace with a `CronJob` and delete unassigned PVCs, or those that match a certain selector.

But I don't think there is any *inherent* ability to do that, given that (at least in my own usage) it's reasonable to scale a `StatefulSet` up and down, and when scaling it back up then one would actually desire that the `Pod` regain its identity in the `StatefulSet`, which typically includes any persisted data.

Comment: Thanks! Both are good ideas. I ended up with writing an operator that consumes Pod events and acts on them.
I agree on the identity but in my special use case the PVCs become stale after a given time. New PVCs are based on more recent snapshots, though

Answer (score 0):

there is a discussion in the kubernetes community, https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55045, you can keep an eye on it